# How to directly access a certain part of a text file in g++?

Tags: c++, g++, seek

I have a text file containing a number of records. Each record is stored on a single line that is 100 characters long.

Let's say I want to directly access the nth record.  I could do it using a for loop, reading in n lines until I get to the record.

But how could I access it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the each line is exactly 100 characters long and the line ending is always `\n` (i.e. no `\r\n` stuff) and there's no blank lines and people won't use 1 tab for 8 spaces etc. you can use (with ifstream)

```
fin.seekg(101 * n, ios::beg);  // Assume the initial record has n=0.
```

or (with FILE*)

```
fseek(f, 101 * n, SEEK_SET);
```

If you are unsure of any of the preconditions, use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use the the [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/) function:

```
ifstream is("test.txt");
is.seekg ( (n-1)*100, ios::beg); // move the get pointer to the beg of nth record.
```